# Avoid updation of cloned testcase when master copy is updated in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, clone, testcase, cloning

I have a Master Copy of test cases, which I will be cloning for every testing cycle. 
Changes in Master Copy test cases gets reflected in already cloned test cases. How can i avoid this?

Comment: No, not yet resolved. I am using VSTS. Not sure if your solution is on VSTS or other tool. You do not have actions on right click on test case

Comment: Create copy of work item is there but add to suite option is not present. Also I want bulk of test cases to be copied to other suit

Answer (score 0):

> Avoid updation of cloned testcase when master copy is updated in VSTS

AFAIK, Azure devops offers two types of copy operations for test suites and test cases, namely, `copy` and `clone`. Copy uses a mechanism called shallow copy that simply creates a reference to the artifact. If any amendment is made to the artifact, it reflects into all its references. Clone uses a mechanism called deep copy; the new artifacts have no reference back to its origin and is not impacted by any updates made to the original artifact.

So, you need to create a clone of the test case, for that you may use the following steps:

1. Go the test case and right click on it.
2. Click on Create Copy and add to suite option in the list.
3. Make the change if you want (Here you can modify test case
   independently without affecting other).
4. Click on Save and Close.
5. Now drag and drop that test case to other suites.

You could check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/mtm/copying-and-cloning-test-suites-and-test-cases?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.